# jQuery Coupon Uses Limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, coupon

I have code in jQuery to add different coupon codes, but I want to add limit to the discount code usage.

For example users can use the `offer10` code 5 times, `offer20` 10 times and `offer30` 3 times.

```js
jQuery('#addPromo').click(function(e) {
  var getPromo = jQuery('#promoTxt').val();
  if (getPromo == "Offer10") {
    jQuery("#promo").val("Price $100");
  } else if (getPromo == "Offer20") {
    jQuery("#promo").val("Price $200");
  } else if (getPromo == "Offer30") {
    jQuery("#promo").val("Price $300");
  } else {
    jQuery("#promo").val("Price $400");
  }
});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<label> 
  Add your promo here 
  <input id="promoTxt" type="text" name="promo"> 
</label>
<div id="addPromo" class="btn btn-primary">Add Promo</div>
<label>
  Discounted Price<br>
  <san class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap promo">
    <input type="text" name="promo" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="promo" aria-invalid="false">
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Firstly, do you mean that you want to limit these per page, or you want to limit the usage across every order the user ever makes? If the latter then you will need to store all the user's order history and compare against that - preferably on the server. Also note that this logic is incredibly easy to get around if you do it on the client. This whole thing needs to be done on the server side

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to use it every order user ever makes. Is that any solution? Thanks

Comment: In that case you need to use server-side logic along with a datastore. Client side JS is not suitable for the task at all

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Basically I'm working with Wordpress, Is that any plugin regarding this to achieve this?